# Continuous calls of the <Configure> event in tkinter

Tags: events, tkinter

I am trying to write a function to dynamically resize an image displayed in a tkinter window.
Therefore I bound this function to the `Configure` event:

`connroot.bind( "<Configure>", connresiz)`

My problems are:

1. That the `connresiz()` function gets called 3 times (why 3?) at program start, and
2. More troublesome, that dynamically resizing the window calls the function continuously as I drag the mouse! How can avoid this?

I thought about checking at the simultaneous presence of a `<Configure>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>` events, but I don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official tk documentation, `<Configure>` events fire "whenever its size, position, or border width changes, and sometimes when it has changed position in the stacking order." This can happen several times during startup.

It is called continuously while you resize the window because the size of the widget is changing. That's what it's defined to do. You can't prevent it from being called, though you can certainly modify what you do in the callback. For example, you could delay resizing the image until you've not received another `<Configure>` event for a second or two -- which likely means the user has stopped interactive resizing.

Comment: Bryan, Peter, thanks for your help. I followed Bryan's suggestion since I need the program to work on different platforms. With a check on change of window size, a "_after" command, and a flag to prevent more than one after calls, it worked

Comment: @alessandro could you please post the code you managed to make work? I tried Peter's solution and indeed doesn't work when resizing via window borders (I'm on Linux)

Comment: @Emanuele I'm really sorry, but 6 years ago I changed the code to insert the floating window inside a Tkinter frame, so that completely changed the resize process - and I searched, but cannot find archived copies of the old code...

Answer (score 4):

**1)** We don't know that, since we can't see your code...

**2)** Short answer is: you can't, because that's exactly what `<Configure>` event does! Long answer, you can, with a little trick/hack. Since anytime the window is changing, it will call all the binded functions to `<Configure>`, and the same happens anytime as the mouse button released (right after the last `<Configure>` call) we can create a flag/switch which will tell us, if the window was "configured" then we can check that switch anytime the mouse button is released, and switch it back to the default value after we ran some actions.

So if you want the image to resized only, when the mouse was released and the window was changed this is the code you need:

```
from tkinter import *

class Run:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.clicked = False
        self.root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.image_resize)
        self.root.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.click(True))
    def image_resize(self, event):
        if self.clicked:
            print("I'm printed after <Configure>.")  # the action goes here!
            self.click(False)
    def click(self, value):
        self.clicked = value

app = Run()
app.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You might not always (or ever) get the `<ButtonRelease-1>` event if the window is resized via the window borders. That is because the button press originates outside of the tkinter window. I think this is somewhat platform and window manager dependent.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that, since I'm on OS X it is working as I expected.. Anyway a resize-watcher can be added instead: get width-height of window, store it, and an `after` callback can be added that is watching for the change -- and this could replace the mouse release. But that is an awful hack:P