# Continuous call of the <Configure> event in tkinter (follow up)

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling, window-resize

I'm new to Python/Tkinter and I'm really stuck here... I am trying to design a fairly responsive GUI and in one of the frames I need to display a vertical list of widgets that might not fit all at the same time. If the user resizes the window, I'd like to compute the amount of items that can fit in the new size and finally redraw the "visible" list. I'm using the `root.bind('<Configure>', do_something)` to trigger the redraw.

PROBLEM: binding to the `<configure>` event triggers the command many times for each single resize action. I'd like to be able to determine when the resizing have been completed (and the mouse button released), and redraw just once.

I have read the answers to this [previously posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747904/continuous-call-of-the-configure-event-in-tkinter?rq=1) (very relevant and basically identical to my case), but the first answer doesn't provide any code and I sincerely couldn't figure out how to follow the advice, while the second answer gives the code but it doesn't solve the problem. One of the comments to this second answer already suggests that it might not work because the ButtonRelease-1 event is not inside the window (since it is a resize). And in fact on my OS doesn't work (Win10).

Could someone provide me with a solution, or a workaround, to help me? If possible, I'd like the solution to be applicable to either Windows and Linux/Debian systems. Below you can see how my code looks like.

Many thanks for any help.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyListOfStuff(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.redraw()

def redraw(self):
    # (re)populate the frame with as many widgets as possible

class MyApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.child_frame = MyListOfStuff(self)
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.resize_detected)

def resize_detected(self, *args):
    self.child_frame.redraw()
    # HERE LIES THE PROBLEM... 
    # This method gets called multiple times per second during the resizing 
    # of the main window, and the user experience is very bad because the 
    # resize action is not smooth and fluid. I'd like to call it only AFTER 
    # the resize has been completed (and quite possibly after the mouse 
    # button has been released).

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_app = MyApp(root)
    my_app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Don't post your whole code, create a new minimal program that exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for the tip, I've updated the answer and inserted some code that should explain the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the suggestion in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17749854/2688066)?

The binded callback could employ `time.time()` to store the time of current call and if it is called again say within two seconds, then don't take action.

```
import time

def your_class:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.last_callback_time = time.time()
        # ... other init
# More stuff in your class
# ...
    def configure_callback(self, event):
        cur_time = time.time()
        if (cur_time - self.last_callback_time) > 2:
             # Do intended stuff
        self.last_callback_time = time.time()
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I would have tried to use the first answer but I couldn't figure out the code to do that (novice here...). So thanks for providing me that! As a suggestion for other people that could encounter the same problem... I've tried to dynamically compute, during the resize, how many widgets I can fit, and redraw the frame only if the amount varies. Also this solution works pretty well.

Comment: Hi, this is not a great solution, because this is at risk of losing resize messages (say by double clicking the top border of a window). Is there perhaps a way to get the list of pending events and check there is no more resize outstanding event, and in case it is, skip current draw?