# Is there any way to track the geometry of tkinter without using while True

Tags: python, tkinter

In my GUI, I wanted to check if the tab was resized or not by the user.
I tried with while loop keeping it True,but because of the while loop the actual tab(GUI) is not running.
so I need help in correcting my code.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("450x300")
chk_a=root.geometry()
while True:
    a=root.geometry()
    length_a=len(a)
    checker=""
    for i in range(7):
        checker=checker+a[i]
    if checker !=chk_a:
        print("Size of the tab is changed")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [continuous call of the Configure event in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747904/continuous-call-of-the-configure-event-in-tkinter)

Comment: I did check the question,my problem is somewhat similar...

Comment: but do you have the link for the python documentation for tkinter configure

Comment: I'm not clear on how to get documentation for tkinter at all.... the site I used (and a lot of my older questions link to) is no longer available so I'm not sure.  Retracted my close vote because you are right, it is related but not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [some documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#events) I managed to track down:

> `<Configure>` The widget changed size (or location, on some platforms).
> The new size is provided in the width and height attributes of the
> event object passed to the callback.

here is a working example:

```
import tkinter as tk

last_size = (None, None)
def onresize(ev):
    if ev.widget is not root:
        return #some widget other than root window resized, ignore.
    global last_size
    new_size = (ev.width, ev.height)
    if last_size != new_size:
        print("window size changed", new_size)
        last_size = new_size

root = tk.Tk()

root.bind("<Configure>", onresize)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: so basically using the <configure> you were able to do this ryt?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ryt", but I'm pretty sure you need to call `mainloop` for anything to work, not sure how you'd get a while loop to work at all. In order to get code to run during the mainloop it needs to be event based.

Comment: Got your point, actually, this code which I posted isn't the actual file's code, rather I created this code just before asking this question. That's why I missed out a few things
thanks, mate for helping me out:)

Comment: This code has a somewhat serious flaw: any binding on root will fire for every widget. Thus, when the user resizes the window then the function will be called for every widget in the window. You should check that `ev.window` is the root window and not do anything otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that, wouldn't have caught it since I had no inner widgets.  @Hafeezh want to make sure you see Bryan's comment, I fixed my code block to account for it.

Comment: Should `ev.window` be `ev.widget` instead?

Comment: Thanks, mate for helping me out, I did run this code on my file works fine 
thanks